# NULL Database Record Returned After Reading Database Record Immediately After Insert

Tags: java, spring, jms

I'm using Spring JMS with the JPA Hibernate implementation and I'm seeing an intermittent issue with a insert and then instant read of the same record.

**web application flow:**

-Data gets posted to my web applications web service and the data is sent to a Glassfish OpenMQ queue (STUInputQ below).
-com.api.listener.backoffice.STUMessageListener reads the STUInputQ queue and does a insert into our Oracle Database and then sends a message (with the new database primary key) to another queue (ArchiveQ below).
-com.api.listener.backoffice.StorableMessageListener reads the ArchiveQ queue and attempts to do an read of the database using the primary key of the database record that was inserted by com.api.listener.backoffice.STUMessageListener.

**Problem:**

Sometimes (about 18%) the read operation in StorableMessageListener returns null, even though the record does exist.  It seems to me the insert commit hasn't processed before the read occurs even though the insert returns the sequence generated primary key.  I've put a unix timestamp at the end of the method that inserts the data and the one that reads it and when the issue occurs the unix timestamps are the same, so it seems as though the read gets the message before the commit is final.

**Temporary Solution:**

I've added some logic to sleep the thread and that ensures that I never get a null with the database read.  I don't really think the thread sleep is a long term solution.  Any ideas on why it seems the STUMessageListener isn't able to commit the transaction before the StorableMessageListener reads it?

**Dependencies:**

hibernate-core.3.3.2.GA

hibernate-entitymanager-3.4.0.GA

spring 3.0.6.RELEASE

Java 1.5

**Spring Configuration:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
            <beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
                xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
                xmlns:util="http://www.springframework.org/schema/util"
                xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
                xmlns:aop="http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop"
                xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
                xmlns:hz="http://www.hazelcast.com/schema/spring"
                xsi:schemaLocation="
                http://www.hazelcast.com/schema/spring
                http://www.hazelcast.com/schema/spring/hazelcast-spring-2.5.xsd
                http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
                http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
                http://www.springframework.org/schema/util
                http://www.springframework.org/schema/util/spring-util-3.0.xsd
                http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
                http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.0.xsd
                http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx
                http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx-3.0.xsd
                http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop
                http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop/spring-aop-3.0.xsd">

                <!-- Generic -->
                <context:annotation-config />
                <context:component-scan base-package="myapp.api" />
                <aop:aspectj-autoproxy/>

                <!-- JPA -->
                <bean class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.support.PersistenceAnnotationBeanPostProcessor" />

                <tx:annotation-driven />

                <bean class="org.springframework.dao.annotation.PersistenceExceptionTranslationPostProcessor" />

                <bean id="entityManagerFactory" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean">
                    <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
                    <property name="jpaVendorAdapter" ref="jpaVendorAdapter" />
                    <property name="persistenceUnitName" value="MyApp" />
                    <property name="jpaProperties">
                        <props>
                            <prop key="hibernate.use_sql_comments">true</prop>
                            <prop key="hibernate.generate_statistics">true</prop>
                            <prop key="hibernate.archive.autodetection">class</prop>
                            <prop key="hibernate.cache.use_second_level_cache">true</prop>
                            <prop key="hibernate.cache.provider_class">com.hazelcast.hibernate.provider.HazelcastCacheProvider</prop>
                            <prop key="hibernate.cache.use_query_cache">true</prop>
                            <prop key="hibernate.cache.use_minimal_puts">true</prop>
                        </props>
                    </property>
                </bean>


               <hz:hazelcast id="instance">
                    <hz:config>
                         //rest of Hazelast config maps here
                    </hz:config>
                </hz:hazelcast>

                <hz:hibernate-region-factory id="regionFactory" instance-ref="instance"/>

                <!-- Define JPA Provider Adapter -->
                <bean id="jpaVendorAdapter" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaVendorAdapter">
                    <property name="showSql" value="true" />
                    <property name="generateDdl" value="true" />
                    <property name="databasePlatform" value="org.hibernate.dialect.OracleDialect" />
                </bean>

                <bean id="dataSourceTarget" class="oracle.jdbc.pool.OracleDataSource" destroy-method="close">
                    <property name="URL" value="jdbc:oracle:thin:@server:1525:name" />
                    <property name="user" value="test" />
                    <property name="password" value="123" />
                    <property name="connectionCachingEnabled" value="true" />
                    <property name="connectionCacheProperties">
                        <props merge="default">
                            <prop key="MinLimit">5</prop>
                            <prop key="MaxLimit">50</prop>
                        </props>
                    </property>
                </bean>

                <bean id="dataSource" class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.LazyConnectionDataSourceProxy">
                    <property name="targetDataSource" ref="dataSourceTarget"/>
                </bean>


                <bean id="transactionManager" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager">
                    <property name="entityManagerFactory" ref="entityManagerFactory"/>
                    <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource"/>
                </bean>

                <tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="transactionManager" proxy-target-class="false"/>

                <bean id="genericDAO" class="myapp.api.dao.impl.GenericDAOImpl">
                    <constructor-arg>
                        <value>java.io.Serializable</value>
                    </constructor-arg>
                </bean>

                <bean id="springContextHolder" class="myapp.api.util.SpringContextHolder" factory-method="getInstance" />

        <bean id="executionInterceptor" class="myapp.api.listener.backoffice.ExecutionInterceptor" />

        <!-- JNDI-->
        <bean id="jndiTemplate" class="org.springframework.jndi.JndiTemplate"/>

        <!-- JMS -->
        <bean id="jmsQueueConnectionFactory"  class="org.springframework.jndi.JndiObjectFactoryBean">
            <property name="jndiTemplate">
                <ref bean="jndiTemplate"/>
            </property>
            <property name="jndiName" value="${jms.jndi.qconnectionfactory}">

            </property>
        </bean>
        <bean id="myJMSConnectionFactory" class="com.api.model.vo.backoffice.OpenMqConnectionFactoryBean">
            <property name="imqAddressList" value="${jms.imq.url}" />
            <property name="imqDefaultUsername" value="${jms.imq.user}" />
            <property name="imqDefaultPassword" value="${jms.imq.password}" />
            <property name="imqHost" value="${jms.imq.host}" />
            <property name="imqPort" value="${jms.imq.port}" />
        </bean>

        <bean id="stuMessageListener" class="com.api.listener.backoffice.STUMessageListener" />
        <bean id="storeListener" class="com.api.listener.backoffice.StorableMessageListener"/>

        <bean id="executionInterceptor" class="com.api.listener.backoffice.ExecutionInterceptor" />

        <bean id="stuJmsContainer" class="org.springframework.jms.listener.DefaultMessageListenerContainer">
            <property name="connectionFactory" ref="jmsQueueConnectionFactory"/>
            <property name="destinationName" value="STUInputQ"/>
            <property name="sessionTransacted" value="false"/>
            <property name="messageListener" ref="stuMessageListener" />
            <property name="concurrentConsumers" value="5" />
            <property name="maxConcurrentConsumers" value="100" />
            <property name="receiveTimeout" value="30000" />
            <property name="cacheLevelName" value="CACHE_NONE" />

        </bean>
        <bean id="storeJmsContainer" class="org.springframework.jms.listener.DefaultMessageListenerContainer">
            <property name="connectionFactory" ref="jmsQueueConnectionFactory"/>
            <property name="destinationName" value="ArchiveQ"/>
            <property name="sessionTransacted" value="false"/>
            <property name="messageListener" ref="storeListener" />
            <property name="concurrentConsumers" value="5" />
            <property name="maxConcurrentConsumers" value="100" />
            <property name="receiveTimeout" value="30000" />
            <property name="cacheLevelName" value="CACHE_NONE" />

        </bean>

 </beans>
```

**Persistence Configuration:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<persistence version="1.0" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_1_0.xsd">
  <persistence-unit name="com" transaction-type="RESOURCE_LOCAL">
  </persistence-unit>
</persistence>
```

**Classes that insert record:**

```
public class STUMessageListener implements javax.jms.MessageListener{
       @Autowired
       StoringService storingService;

       @Transactional
       public void onMessage(Message message) throws RuntimeException { 
           try {
                Object omsg = ((ObjectMessage) message).getObject();
                if (omsg instanceof StorableMessage) {
                     StorableMessage storableMessage = (StorableMessage) omsg;
                     //StorableMessage insert into Database
                     storingService.store(storableMessage); 

                   //jms logic here to send message to next queue (ArchiveQ)
           }
           catch (Throwable ex) {
                throw new RuntimeException(ex);
            }
   }

     @Service("storingService")
        public class StoringServiceImpl{

            @Autowired
            MessagesDAO messagesDAO;

            @Transactional
            public StorableMessage store(StorableMessage storableMessage) {
                messagesDAO.save(storableMessage);
            }

        }

    @Repository("messagesDAO")
    public class MessagesDAOImpl{
        private Class<T> type
        @PersistenceContext
        EntityManager entityManager;

        public void save(T object) {
           entityManager.persist(object);
        }

        public T findById(Serializable id) {
           return entityManager.find(type, id);
        }
    }
```

**Classes that Read the Database Record:**

```
public class StorableMessageListener implements javax.jms.MessageListener {
    @Autowired
    MessageDAO messageDAO;

    @Transactional
    public void onMessage(Message message) throws RuntimeException {
          if (omsg instanceof StorableMessage) {
               //this is where null is returned for the Messages object 18% of the time
               //sleep thread by 1 second logic here helps eliminate the null Messages object
              //uses same MessageDAO as above 
              Messages msg = messageDAO.findById(storableMessage.getMessageKey());
          }
    }
```

Comment: why have you marked "onMessage()" as @Transactional ? Have you tried removing it ?

Comment: This is legacy code and that is how it was, I'll try removing

Comment: ok. You can try removing it from both the "onMessage" methods. If it still doesnt help, pls post the JMS logic inside STUMessageListener.onMessage().

Answer (score 0):

Try to change the annotation of the insert method as

@Transactional(propagation = Propagation.REQUIRES_NEW)

This will commit the insert as soon as the method finishes.

Comment: Its still null the same amount with that transaction change.

Comment: You change the service method, right? Like -> 
@Transactional(propagation = Propagation.REQUIRES_NEW)
public StorableMessage store(StorableMessage storableMessage) {
                messagesDAO.save(storableMessage);
            }

The requires_new must be in the method of the StoringServiceImpl.